# Map values of a column to another column if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```python
    text         from_id    to_id   position
0   NaN           NaN        NaN    [nan, nan]
1   albumin       NaN        NaN    [0.0, 23.0]
2   hepatoma      NaN        NaN    [93.0, 101.0]
3   NaN          hepatoma  albumin  [nan, nan]
```

I want to create two new columns named `from_position` and `to_position` and I want them to be like this:

```python
        text    from_id     to_id   position      from_position  to_position
    0   NaN      NaN         NaN    [nan, nan]      [nan, nan]   [nan, nan]
    1   albumin  NaN         NaN    [0.0, 23.0]     [nan, nan]   [nan, nan]  
    2   hepatoma NaN         NaN    [93.0, 101.0]   [nan, nan]   [nan, nan]
    3   NaN     hepatoma  albumin   [nan, nan]      [93.0, 101.0]  [0.0, 23.0]
```

Note that it doesn't have to be [nan,nan] it can also be NaN. Moreover, the position values aren't lists of floats, they are strings (I'm ok with converting them).

I tried this

```python
s = full_df_normalized.dropna(subset=['text', 'position']).set_index('text')['position'].to_dict()

cols = ['from_position','to_position']
full_df_normalized[cols] = full_df_normalized[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map(d))
```

But I got this error: `KeyError: "None of [Index(['from_position', 'to_position'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

So, I created 2 empty (NaN) columns named 'from_position','to_position' and ran it again, but they are still NaN.

I also tried this :

```python
for i,row in full_df_normalized.iterrows():
    for key,value in sd.items():
        if key == row['from_id']:
            row['from_position'] == value
```

But once again, the 'from_position' column remains NaN. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution apply mapping for `id` columns from list `cols1`, is necessary same ordering like `col`, last replace missing values by list `[np.nan, np.nan]`:

```
nan = np.nan
full_df_normalized = pd.DataFrame({'text': [nan, 'albumin', 'hepatoma', nan], 'from_id': [nan, nan, nan, 'hepatoma'], 'to_id': [nan, nan, nan, 'albumin'], 'position': [[nan, nan], [0.0, 23.0], [93.0, 101.0], [nan, nan]]})

print (full_df_normalized)
       text   from_id    to_id       position
0       NaN       NaN      NaN     [nan, nan]
1   albumin       NaN      NaN    [0.0, 23.0]
2  hepatoma       NaN      NaN  [93.0, 101.0]
3       NaN  hepatoma  albumin     [nan, nan]

d = full_df_normalized.dropna(subset=['text', 'position']).set_index('text')['position'].to_dict()
```

---

```
cols = ['from_position','to_position']
cols1 = ['from_id','to_id']

f = lambda x:x.map(d).dropna().reindex(full_df_normalized.index,fill_value=[np.nan,np.nan])
full_df_normalized[cols] = full_df_normalized[cols1].apply(f)
print (full_df_normalized)
       text   from_id    to_id      position from_position to_position
0       NaN       NaN      NaN     [nan,nan]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
1   albumin       NaN      NaN    [0.0,23.0]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
2  hepatoma       NaN      NaN  [93.0,101.0]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
3       NaN  hepatoma  albumin     [nan,nan]  [93.0,101.0]  [0.0,23.0]
```

Or you can processing each coumn separately:

```
for c in cols:
    c1 = c.replace('_position', '_id')
    full_df_normalized[c] = full_df_normalized[c1].map(d).dropna().reindex(full_df_normalized.index, fill_value=[np.nan, np.nan])


print (full_df_normalized)
       text   from_id    to_id      position from_position to_position
0       NaN       NaN      NaN     [nan,nan]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
1   albumin       NaN      NaN    [0.0,23.0]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
2  hepatoma       NaN      NaN  [93.0,101.0]    [nan, nan]  [nan, nan]
3       NaN  hepatoma  albumin     [nan,nan]  [93.0,101.0]  [0.0,23.0]
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I still get NaN values in all rows for the columns `from_position` and `to_position`.

Comment: @joasa - so it means not match `text` with columns `from_id, to_id` ?

Comment: Yes, some values are NaN and I think that's the problem

Comment: @joasa - do you think in dictioanry -  `print (d)` ? Because here seems some problem with no match, it means `hepatoma` is `'hepatoma '` ?

Comment: Hi, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` on `full_df_normalized[cols] = full_df_normalized[cols1].apply(f)`

Comment: Sorry the position is a list of strings, not a string as I mentioned incorrectly before

Comment: @joasa - are data confidental?

Comment: Yes unfortunately, that's why I only posted a small subset.

Comment: @joasa - if use both solutions if failed?

Comment: @joasa - added your sample data in question, can you test?

Comment: I'm still getting only nan values in `from_position` and `to_position`. Not sure why

Comment: @joasa - from my sample data for both solutions?

Comment: @joasa - added `d = full_df_normalized.dropna(subset=['text', 'position']).set_index('text')['position'].to_dict()` to answer for complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Using a reshaped DataFrame as intermediate:

```
cols = ['from_id', 'to_id']
df.join(df
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns='position')
 .melt(id_vars='index', value_vars=cols, value_name='text')
 .merge(df.dropna(subset='text'), on='text')
 .pivot('index', 'variable', 'position')
 .rename(columns=lambda s: s.replace('_id', '_position'))
)
```

output:

```
     text   from_id    to_id       position  from_position  to_position
0       NaN       NaN      NaN     [nan, nan]            NaN          NaN
1   albumin       NaN      NaN    [0.0, 23.0]            NaN          NaN
2  hepatoma       NaN      NaN  [93.0, 101.0]            NaN          NaN
3       NaN  hepatoma  albumin     [nan, nan]  [93.0, 101.0]  [0.0, 23.0]
```

Here's the dict output

```python
{'text': [nan, 'albumin', 'hepatoma', nan, nan],
 'from_id': [nan, nan, nan, 'hepatoma', nan],
 'to_id': [nan, nan, nan, 'albumin', nan],
 'position': ['[nan, nan]',
  '[0.0, 23.0]',
  '[93.0, 101.0]',
  '[nan, nan]',
  '[nan, nan]']}
```

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned position is not a list of floats, it's string values.

Comment: @joasa it shouldn't matter for this answer, you can fillna with a string is needed

Comment: I get this error `TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'text' was passed`

Comment: OK, it's the pandas version, use `id_vars=['index']`, or `.pivot(index=['index'], ...)`, not sure which one causes the error

Comment: I tried `pivot(index=['index']` and now I get this : `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: sorry should be `.pivot(index='index', columns='variable', values='position')`, but what was exactly the full error traceback?

Comment: I tried `.pivot(index='index', columns='variable', values='position')` but I get `TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'text' was passed` for line `.merge(full_df_normalized.dropna(subset='text'), on='text')`

Comment: ok, then `full_df_normalized.dropna(subset=['text'])`, which pandas version do you have?

Comment: I have version 1.3.2. Now I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` on `full_df_normalized.join(full_df_normalized`. Sorry the position is a list of strings, not a string as I mentioned incorrectly before

Comment: can you provide the output of `full_df_normalized.heaad().to_dict('list')`? That's why you should always provide a DataFrame constructor, this saves everyone a lot of time ;)